# How do I stop dojo from scrolling to form widgets on focus?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

All form widgets extend from `dijit.form._FormWidgetMixin` which scrolls the window to the widget when it receives focus.

I personally find that this behavior makes most widgets unusable. How can I stop it?

Comment: I personally find the opposite... how do you fill-in forms using only the keyboard if the page doesn't scroll ?

Comment: For widgets that use standard form elements, it should behave as the browser does normally. One example of why I don't like this feature - I have a `dijit/InlineEditBox` using a `ditit/form/Textarea` as the editor. Clicking the text produces a textarea, along with save and cancel buttons. clicking on either button causes the page to scroll to the button. I have to click a second time to actually trigger the button click

Comment: using the keyboard still works just fine for me. It scrolls to the element. I would prefer to enable it as needed (if needed), rather than have lots of random scrolling when clicking on things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo allows you to extend base components using `dojo/_base/lang::extend`. Just make sure to require this module before any require calls that load `dijit/form/_FormWidgetMixin`

```
// Dojo 1.7+ (AMD)
define([
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dijit/form/_FormWidgetMixin"
], function(lang, _FormWidget){
    lang.extend(_FormWidget, {
        scrollOnFocus:false
    });
});
```

Here is the same for pre-AMD dojo:

```
// Dojo < 1.7
dojo.require("dijit.form._FormWidget");
dojo.extend(dijit.form._FormWidget, {
    scrollOnFocus:false
});
```